# Java - srcset attribute - split - handle urls with commas and attribute values separated with comma

Tags: java, html, split, srcset, urlsplit

Splitting scrset attribute value separated with comma is ambiguous. There is no quite smart solutions as URLs may contain commas in the path section without being percent encoded and multiple urls could be separated with comma.

Looking for a smart solution to handle to both cases in java.

Ex - scrset = "a.png 1x, a/src/b.png?qlt=0,1,2&test=9,0 3x, ssgh.png,test.png"

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#parsing-a-srcset-attribute